# One jquery function doesn't work when it is called in a div that another jquery function is applied to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Stackoverflow buds. (I know some of you don't like any text devoted to anything other than tech, but I love this community... and an occasional effusivee expression is inescapable for me.)

Anyway... In my Rails 3.2 app I have this means in my javascript file to pass actions to a controller to make minor changes in data.

Sample view snippet:

```
<%= select_tag @item.id, options_for_select([1,2,3], 1), :class => "on_change", :controller => "controller_name", :action => "change_priority", :reload =>"page" %>
```

Sitengine.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    $(".on_change").change(function() {
        $("#spinner").show();
        var ans = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var controller = $(this).attr('controller');
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var reload = $(this).attr('reload');
        var url = "/" + controller + "/" + id + "/" + action + "/?ans=" + ans;
        $.post(url, id, function(html) {
            if (reload === 'page') {
                window.location.reload(true);
            } else if (reload === 'div') {
                $("#spinner").hide();
            } else {
                $("#spinner").hide();
            };
        });
    });
    ...
});
```

Controller Action:

```
def change_priority
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.unpdate_attributes(:priority => params[:ans])
  render :nothing => true
end
```

It all works and I love it! But... When I try to use ".on_change" in another function it stops working. I'm not the javascript guru that some of you are.

Here's the the function that keeps a div from leaving the page view if it is scrolled. It is not between the $(document).ready(function() while the prior function is.

```
function UpdateDiv() {
    $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop() + 31,
           floatingDiv = $(".floatingDiv", this)

       if (scrollTop > offset.top) {
           floatingDiv.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingDiv.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });      
       };
    });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {
   var clonedDiv;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedDiv = $(".persist-div", this);
       clonedDiv
         .before(clonedDiv.clone())
         .css("width", clonedDiv.width())
         .addClass("floatingDiv");
   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateDiv)
    .trigger("scroll");
});
```

I've tried adding the ".on_change" script inside the code but that doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by your question.  But just as a guess did you try to bind to the body on change event instead. Its proper to attach to the body incase of unexpected DOM Events

```
$('body').on('change', '.on_change', function () {
 $("#spinner").show();
        var ans = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var controller = $(this).attr('controller');
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var reload = $(this).attr('reload');
        var url = "/" + controller + "/" + id + "/" + action + "/?ans=" + ans;
        $.post(url, id, function(html) {
            if (reload === 'page') {
                window.location.reload(true);
            } else if (reload === 'div') {
                $("#spinner").hide();
            } else {
                $("#spinner").hide();
            };
        });
})
```

Comment: Huh... I never knew that existed. Will give it a shot now.

Comment: You da man! Will go to jquery docs to try and understand that is going on in the change you suggested.

Comment: It worked sweet I was hoping that's what it was, basically if anything changes the DOM, your events can get messed up, but when you bind to the body.on method your binding directly to the body of the DOM so it should always be there